# command "dir" doesn't work with libcurl language C

Tags: c, ftp, libcurl, passive-mode

I'm trying to send a "DIR" command on an ftp server with the fonction below:

```
void cpyFileInServeur(char *src, char *dest, char *filename, serveur server)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
    char *userpwd = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    sprintf(userpwd, "%s:%s", server.user, server.passwd);
    header = curl_slist_append(header, "dir");
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, server.url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, userpwd);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, header);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            printf ("Erreur === %d\n", res);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("Success .... == %d\n", res);
        }
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Error:

> 500 DIR not understood
>
> QUOT command failed with 500

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdnqM.png)

when I use the terminal, I get the same error.
But if I use the command "pass", then it works

image below

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpuW7.png)

Thanks for help.

Comment: `dir` isn't an FTP command; `dir` is a command understood by your FTP *client*.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959 read this RFC.